# How to detect if UI Label was tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make a choose-your-own adventure game that changes the text of two labels (the user choices) depending on which label the user taps. I figured I would just do a very nested if-else statement rather than bother with trying to implement a binary tree. I know how to attach the gesture recognizer to a label (I think):

```
let tapped1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(VCGame.usrChose1))  
choice1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true  
choice1.addGestureRecognizer(tapped1)  

let tapped2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(VCGame.usrChose2))  
choice2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true  
choice2.addGestureRecognizer(tapped2)
```

and I can define what to do when the label is touched in the usrChose1 and usrChose2 functions, however, those functions only work once: the first time the function is chosen and my game has more than just one choice. From there, the labels will just do the same thing if the user touches them.

How would I go about having a condition inside the if-else statement that evaluates to true or false if label1 or label2 is tapped?

Here's the code for usrChoice1 and usrChoice2, for clarification

```
func usrChose1(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap 1 working")
    choice1.text = "choice1.1"
    choice2.text = "choice1.2"
}

func usrChose2(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap2 working")
    choice1.text = "update2.1";
    choice2.text = "update2.2"
}
```

Below image shows my requirement :

[image: here's a chart i made to help illustrate the logic]

Comment: What do you want to do if the user tap on choice1 label second time?

Comment: @user1000 so, if choice1 was tapped then the two labels would update to something like "update1.1" and "update1.2" respectively. that, i can make happen so far. but then the game has to continue and so if the user clicks choice1, which now reads "update1.1", the two labels should update AGAIN to offer two NEW choices, like "update1.1.1" and "1.1.2"

Comment: what do you mean?like what?

Comment: If you added Gesture on Label, and didn't remove that. Then gesture methods (usrChose1, usrChose2) will call on each time when you tap on Label.  So what you mean by **those functions only work once** ?

Comment: @user1000 sorry, i pressed 'enter' by accident

Comment: @Surjeet i have the code that adds the gesture recognizer to each label and then connects it to call the usrChoice1 function if choice1 is tapped and the usrChoice2 function if choice2 is tapped. however, the code inside usrChoice1 and usrChoice2 can only change the label text once and can't "listen" for further taps, if that makes sense

Comment: @Surjeet so usrChoice1 can change the labels to read two new choices (let's say "update1.1" and "update1.2") and usrChoice2 can change the labels to read two other choices ("update2.1" and "update2.2"), but then if you tap on the label, it just keeps rechanging the labels to the same text

Comment: @glenohumeral13 Edit your question and post your usrChoice1() and usrChoice2() as well for proper understanding of issue.

Comment: I think you can maintain an array  and update the label by tapping , a counter can give you the desired value, see my answer, see if it helps you

Comment: Why don't you use UIButton instead of uilabel ?

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava i tried, but i ran into the same key problem: i don't know how to detect if one was tapped and use that for an if-else statement. adding the tap recognizer to the label is fine so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement, I have tried the following:

I have made a dummy project with two labels inside a view controller

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var choice1Label: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var choiceLabel2: UILabel!

        var tapStart: Bool = false

        var levelType1: Level?
        var levelType2: Level?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()





                let tapped1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(usrChose1))
                choice1Label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                choice1Label.addGestureRecognizer(tapped1)

                let tapped2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(usrChose2))
                choiceLabel2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                choiceLabel2.addGestureRecognizer(tapped2)

                setup()

        }

        var currentLevel1: Level?
        var currentLevel2: Level?


        func setup() {
                let lb2Child1Child1 = Level(text: "2.1.1", subLevels: nil)
                let lb2Child1Child2 = Level(text: "2.1.2", subLevels: nil)


                let lb1Child1Child1 = Level(text: "1.1.1", subLevels: nil)
                let lb1Child1Child2 = Level(text: "1.1.2", subLevels: nil)

                let lb1Child2Child1 = Level(text: "1.2.1", subLevels: nil)
                let lb1Child2Child2 = Level(text: "1.2.2", subLevels: nil)

                let lb1Child1 = Level(text: "1.1", subLevels: [lb1Child1Child1, lb1Child1Child2])
                let lb1Child2 = Level(text: "1.2", subLevels: [lb1Child2Child1, lb1Child2Child2])


                let lb2Child1 = Level(text: "2.1", subLevels: [lb2Child1Child1, lb2Child1Child2])
                let lb2Child2 = Level(text: "2.2", subLevels: nil)


                levelType1 = Level(text: "1", subLevels: [lb1Child1, lb1Child2])
                levelType2 = Level(text: "2", subLevels: [lb2Child1, lb2Child2])
                choice1Label.text = levelType1!.text ?? ""
                choiceLabel2.text = levelType2!.text ?? ""


        }

        func usrChose1(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {

                if !tapStart {

                        currentLevel1 = levelType1

                        tapStart = true
                }

                if let subLevelsArray = currentLevel1?.subLevels {

                        print(subLevelsArray[0].text ?? "")
                        print(subLevelsArray[1].text ?? "")

                        choice1Label.text = subLevelsArray[0].text ?? ""
                        choiceLabel2.text = subLevelsArray[1].text ?? ""

                        currentLevel1 = subLevelsArray[0]
                        currentLevel2 = subLevelsArray[1]
                }


        }

        func usrChose2(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
                //print("tap2 working")
               // choice1Label.text = "update2.1";
                //choiceLabel2.text = "update2.2"



                if !tapStart {


                        currentLevel2 = levelType2

                        tapStart = true
                }

                if let subLevelsArray = currentLevel2?.subLevels {

                        print(subLevelsArray[0].text ?? "")
                        print(subLevelsArray[1].text ?? "")
                        choice1Label.text = subLevelsArray[0].text ?? ""
                        choiceLabel2.text = subLevelsArray[1].text ?? ""
                        currentLevel1 = subLevelsArray[0]
                        currentLevel2 = subLevelsArray[1]

                }
        }

}
```

I have made a class named Level to represent a single level and each level contains sublevels

Level.swift

```
import UIKit

class Level {
        var text: String?

        var subLevels: [Level]?


        init(text: String, subLevels: [Level]?) {
                self.text = text
                self.subLevels = subLevels ?? nil

        }




}
```

Comment: almost! but then that only changes the first label and cycles through those options linearly, not taking into account that if the user chooses one option, the branch diverges and certain options are now closed off

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/aWZf6W0.png here's a chart i made to help illustrate it!

Comment: @glenohumeral13 You have two labels, if labels for choice 1 and choice 2 , if the user tapped on choice 1 label this label will show 1.1 and when user tapped on choice 2 label , this label will show 2.1, am I right? If you can show your UI for labels then it will greatly help us

Comment: yes, you're right. what do you mean by my UI? like the storyboard?

Comment: @glenohumeral13 how many labels you have on screen? yes if possible storyboard or run on simulator screen shot

Comment: i have 2 labels and 2 gesture recognizers [here's a screenshot of the storyboard!](http://i.imgur.com/1B98gFT.png)

Comment: @glenohumeral13 if user taps on choice1 label you also want to change choice2 text or only of choice 1 label?

Comment: yes, if choice1 is selected then both choice1 and choice2 should be changed to show the two new options!

Comment: @glenohumeral13 if the choice 1 label contains 1.1.1 then what should be the choice label 2 contain? and if the user taps on choice 1 now what should be the next value?

Comment: the string of numbers after "choice" is a handy convention im using to make things clearer. so it's it's 1.1.1 that means the user clicked the choice 1 label three times in a row. so the label displayed alongside that (choice 2) would be 1.1.2. if the user clicks on "choice1.1.1" then the next two labels shown would be "choice1.1.1.1" and "choice1.1.1.2"

Comment: @glenohumeral13 it means the user cannot come back to level to say 2.2?

Comment: nope, that's why i think a large if-else statement will work best here, because the branches will never converge/be able to go back, so every branch is mutually exclusive

Comment: @glenohumeral13 say the label1 currently displays 1.1.1 and label2 1.1.2 and then how will you display 2.2 in future?

Comment: well, 2.2 can only be accessed if the user chose choice 2 the first time. choosing choice2 will result in choice2.1 and choice2.2 being displayed. if the user then chooses choice2.2, the labels will be updated with choice2.2.1 and choice2.2.2; so if the user were to see choice1.1.1 and 1.1.2, that means they chose choice1, then choice1 again (choice1.1), and are now choosing between choice1.1.1 and choice1.1.2; they will never see choice2.2 because their branch diverged

Comment: @glenohumeral13 there can only be two sublevels like for 1.1 there are only 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 or there is also 1.1.3?

Comment: no, just 1.1.1 and 1.1.2, so yes: two sublevels, so to speak. never a third choice

Comment: @glenohumeral13 ok good, one more question say label 1 has 1.1.1 and label 2 has 1.1.2 , now if the user taps on label 2, it will update the values as for label1 1.1.2.1 and for label2 1.1.2.2, am I right?

Comment: @glenohumeral13 see my updated answer, if it helps you solve your problem, please accept the answer, if you face problem please ask, thanks

Comment: oh, wow, YES it worked! thank you so so much! you've been very very helpful and i wish i could give you double the points!

Comment: @glenohumeral13 No worries, I learned alot  implementing this, glad I could help, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `UILabel` or `UIView` whatever is container.

Add 2 different `Int` variables in each functions `usrChose1` and `usrChose2` respectively, which will be work as a counter.

```
var i = 0
var j = 0
func usrChose1(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    i++
    print("Total clicked label 1 :::",i)
}
func usrChose2(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    j++
    print("Total clicked label 2 :::",j)
}
```

Comment: I added two (one for each label) programmatically with the code snippet in the original question, I think. But I just don't know how to repeatedly check if a label was tapped, like having an if(tapped) sort of thing